# Rolling-curl Codeigniter library

Tags: codeigniter, curl

I've been using this rolling-curl library with success outside of Codeigniter http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

I want to use the library with Codeigniter but cannot get it to work.

I've created a file called Rollingcurl.php and placed in codeigniter's application/library folder. In this file I've copied the originals RollingCurl.php file's content (see RollingCurl.php file in link posted above).

My controller looks like this:

```
class Rolling_curl extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();      
}

function index(){

    $this->load->library('rollingcurl', 'request_callback');
    $this->rollingcurl->request("http://www.google.com");
    $this->rollingcurl->execute();

}

function request_callback($response, $info, $request) {
        // parse the page title out of the returned HTML
        if (preg_match("~<title>(.*?)</title>~i", $response, $out)) {
                $title = $out[1];
        }
        echo "<b>$title</b><br />";
        print_r($info);
    print_r($request);
        echo "<hr>";
}
```

In the index function I'm loading the rollingcurl library I've created from the orginal RollingCurl.php and passing the parameter 'request_callback', which is the name of the other function in the controller (see orginal rolling-curl example: http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/source/browse/trunk/example.php).

But, it doesn't work... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that `request_callback` cannot be called since it's in the Rolling_Curl namespace/class.

Comment: How would you go about solving it?

Comment: When you're constructing your library, you should pass the callback reference instead of the name. Like `library('rollingcurl',array($this,'request_callback'));` Then into the library, you'd call `call_user_func_array($reference,$params)`

Comment: @AndreasBloch If you are able to find a solution for this please post an answer.

Comment: I skipped this approach altogether and started using phantomjs for crawling.